# Compute the determinant-like sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A = (a_{ij} \mid i,j = 1, \ldots, 2n)$ be a skew-symmetric matrix. I want to compute the following sum:
$$
   S = \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{2n}} \mathop{\mathrm{sgn}}(\sigma)\, a_{\sigma(1)\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{\sigma(2n-1)\sigma(2n)},
$$
where $S_{2n}$ is the set of all permutations of $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$. My question is whether there is some beautiful formula for $S$, maybe involving determinant of $A$, or not?

Comment: You might want to specify that the second factor in the product is $a_{\sigma(3),\sigma(4)}$ rather than $a_{\sigma(2),\sigma(3)}$, so there are $n$ factors in all, not $2n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [pfaffian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian)! See the wiki article for ways of computing it.

Comment: More precisely, it is $2^nn!$ times the Pfaffian.